# Tampermonkey doesn't load on github until refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, tampermonkey

Everyone says use the `waitForKeyElements` utility.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Github raw to cdn to rawgit
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Add a CDN button to button group
// @author       You
// @match        https://github.com/*/*/blob/*/*
// @include      https://github.com/*/*/blob/*/*
// @grant        none
// @require      https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
// @require      https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// ==/UserScript==

waitForKeyElements('a#raw-url', addCDN);

function addCDN(rawURL) {
    var href = rawURL.attr('href');
    var cdn = href.replace('/raw', '');
    var button = '<a href="https://cdn.rawgit.com' + cdn + '" class="btn btn-sm BtnGroup-item" target="_blank">CDN</a>';
    $(button).appendTo($('.BtnGroup'));
}
```

I tried going to github homepage then navigate to the file. But it doesn't show that the script is running in tampermonkey. I refreshed the page then it's okay! Going to the homepage then navigate to the file it's there! I tried again to close the tab and freshly open the github homepage from a new tab then the problem's there again.

Is something missing in my code? I also tried `$(function() {});` or the ready function. It's not working.

Comment: waitForKeyElements, that's a github thing? have you tried the different [@run-at](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_run_at) options?

Comment: I tried document-idle bit nothing happened.

Comment: right now, I just tried all @run-at options but nothing happens

Comment: Well, I just installed your script (as it is in the question) - and `addCDN` gets called fine on navigating to an appropriate page - perhaps chrome works differently though (firefox here_

Comment: Thanks for trying. Maybe I need something to make it work for chrome.

Comment: The observed behavior in Tampermonkey is correct. Userscripts are executed on the first full page load so only those userscripts run that match that initial URL. This is the historical behavior, also that of extension's content script, so if Greasemonkey doesn't follow the suit, it's just another bug/quirk of Greasemonkey. You need to use `@match https://github.com/*`

Comment: It worked! thank you very much @wOxxOm

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for the answer @wOxxOm

using `@match https://github.com/*` was the answer.